# How to move SQL user database to SharePoint?

Tags: database, sql

I have a SQL and a Access database which I need to import to SharePoint. These database contains information collected from my Internet site like registration info, usernames  etc.

Is this possible to do it? I have read somewhere that it can be done using BCS. But I am unable to find more information on it.

Can someone please help me out?

Comment: Do you want your users to authenticate into SharePoint using these data? Or do you just want the data accessible in SharePoint for internal consumption (not necessarily for authentication)?

Comment: I need e data accessible in SharePoint for internal consumption (not necessarily for authentication). Tx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few things come to mind, using BCS and external lists to bring the content in, creating a DVWP with the database as a data source, using SSRS to bring the data into SharePoint.

Some references on the BCS, [Link 1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee556826.aspx), [Link 2](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/ee518675), [Link 3](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee661740.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

You can write your own authentification provaider. I think this articles will helpful:

[Forms Authentication in SharePoint Products and Technologies (Part 1): Introduction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb975136%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

[Forms Authentication in SharePoint Products and Technologies (Part 2): Membership and Role Provider Samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb975135%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

Comment: Based on the comments above, this isn't what the user wants, although it is a good answer for setting up forms authentication.  He just wants to expose that data in SharePoint.